# WinInet request fails with ERROR_EA_FILE_CORRUPT after InternetQueryDataAvailable returned ERROR_IO_PENDING

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, network-programming, wininet

I'm using async WinInet request to read HTTPS data from a server.

My scenario in few words:

1. Create a request with `InternetUrlOpen` (it returns null)
2. Wait for
   `INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED` notification, store the handle
3. Wait for `INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE`
4. Call `InternetQueryDataAvailable` to know how much data to read using the stored handle
5. Read data via `InternetReadFile` using the stored handle, and go to previous step
6. If `InternetQueryDataAvailable` returns
   `ERROR_IO_PENDING`, then wait for the next `INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE`

But after `InternetQueryDataAvailable` returns `ERROR_IO_PENDING` I receive `INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE` with `dwError=276` which is `ERROR_EA_FILE_CORRUPT`. After that I don't receive any notification for the request, so it looks like the request really fails.

What does it means?

---

Here are some logs:

```
...
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Handle 0x00CC0010 created
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Detecting Proxy
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Cookie found and will be sent with request
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Sending request
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Request sent (1098 Bytes)
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Receiving Response
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Response Received (519 Bytes)

CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Request complete, result=cc0010, err=0
CRequestImpl::onRequestComplete: error=0
CRequestImpl::onRequestComplete: internet data available, 276 bytes
CRequestImpl::onRequestComplete: read 276 bytes
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Receiving Response
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Response Received (1756 Bytes)
CRequestImpl::onRequestComplete: internet data available, 1679 bytes
CRequestImpl::onRequestComplete: read 1679 bytes
...
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Receiving Response
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Response Received (7 Bytes)
CRequestImpl::onRequestComplete: internet data available, 2 bytes
CRequestImpl::onRequestComplete: read 2 bytes
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Receiving Response
CRequestImpl::onRequestComplete: InternetQueryDataAvailable failed with error 997: Overlapped I/O operation is in progress.

CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Response Received (283 Bytes)
CRequestImpl::InternetStatusCallback: Status: Request complete, result=1, err=276
CRequestImpl::onRequestComplete: error=276
CRequestImpl::onRequestComplete: Internet request failed with error 276: The extended attribute file on the mounted file system is corrupt.
```

Comment: I believe `dwError` is only meaningful if `dwResult` indicates failure. You are getting `dwResult` of 1 (aka `TRUE`) which for `InternetQueryDataAvailable` means success. `dwError` is just random garbage.

Comment: I have tested and I think you're right. Thanks for clarifying, it wasn't obvious for me. If you move your comment to an answer I'd accept it.